# htaccess redirect with dynamic variables conflict

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, redirect, url-rewriting, var

I'm working in an old CMS that uses htaccess to rewrite URIs with GET variables into something more user friendly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^animals/(.*)/ secondary.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^animals/(.*) secondary.php?page=$1
```

which results (correctly) in

```
http://www.example.com/animals/duck
```

The problem is I now need to redirect some of those pages to new pages. I've tried:

```
Redirect 301 /animals/goose http://www.example.com/animals/fowl
```

The redirect almost works, but it adds "?page=goose" to the end of the rewritten URI:

```
http://www.example.com/animals/fowl?page=goose
```

I've tried using RewriteRule as well as RewriteCond, but unfortunatley I'm having no luck. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing this before the other rules instead of the Redirect statement. `R=301` is for the redirect and `L` signals that the rule in question is the last rule to be processed.

```
RewriteRule ^animals/goose /animals/fowl [R=301,L]
```

Also you can easily make the slash (just like any other character) optional with a question mark, instead of having two rules.

```
RewriteRule ^animals/(.*)/?$ secondary.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I think I was changing too many things at once. I placed the rule top of the file seems to have fixed my issue. Many thanks.